# Hacer que JPA nombre las tablas en mayuscula

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

Estoy usando JPA con spring boot, hibernate y sql server, funciona bien, pero quisiera que los nombres de las tablas y sus campos en la base de datos los escribe en minusculas, ¿Cómo puedo hacer que lo haga en mayusculas?

Así es como tengo mi properties:

```
    logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
    logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://blablabla;
    spring.datasource.username=usuario
    spring.datasource.password=password
    spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    spring.jpa.show-sql=true
    spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ejemplo:

Class User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="usr")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="username")
    private String username;

    public User(){
        //Empty
    }

    //Getters & setters
}
```

Con el @Table(name="usr") indicas en name el nombre que quieres para la tabla. Y con @Column(name="username") indicas en name el nombre que quieres para el atributo o el campo.

Comment: Me habia equivocado, lo que quiero hacer es que escriba los nombres en mayuscula in embargo tu idea funcionó, gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Primero recuerda que la entidad(Objeto que representa una tabla en la base de datos) le puedes hacer las modificaciones que creas necesario y con respecto a tu pregunta debes tener en cuenta las anotaciones usadas para configurar tú objeto entidad. Entonces una tabla de una base de datos la puedes mapear con las anotaciones.

[Citado por Java EE 7](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Table.html)

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CUST", schema="RECORDS")
public class Customer { ... }
```

[Citado por java EE 5](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Column.html)

```
Example 1:
@Column(name="DESC", nullable=false, length=512)
public String getDescription() { return description; }

Example 2:
@Column(name="DESC",columnDefinition="CLOB NOT NULL",table="EMP_DETAIL")
@Lob
public String getDescription() { return description; }

Example 3:
@Column(name="ORDER_COST", updatable=false, precision=12, scale=2)
public BigDecimal getCost() { return cost; }
```

En conclusión en los atributos de las anotaciones se describen los datos tal cual como lo dejaste en la base de datos y las propiedades de la clase le puede asignar el nombre que creas necesario.

Answer (score 1):

tuve un problema similar utilizando postgresql: el nombre de mi esquema y el de mi tabla están en mayúsculas y tuve errores por esa razón y la solución a esos errores fue:

poner los nombres de esta manera

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "\"PERMISOS\"", schema = "\"USUARIO\"")
```

y agregar esta linea en mi application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physicalstrategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.hysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```